# Decreasing left-margin horizontal spacing of child entry in glossaries-extra with alttree style

Tags: spacing, glossaries, glossaries-extra, bib2gls, horizontal-spacing

I am trying to change horizontal spacing in a glossary. More specifically,

- I am using `glossaries-extra` with `bib2gls`, using `altree` style;
- there are parent entries and child entries in the glossary;
- the hope is to decrease left-margin horizontal spacing for child entries.

Currently, the name of a child node begins where the description of parent node begins (see annotated output).

***Q:*** I would like to shift the child node name more to the left (plus child node description to the left). Otherwise, `alttree` style is desired.

See the following annotated output for more clarifications.

[image: Output with annotations]

**Effort**

My partial solution (***not*** present in MWE) was to add the following code to the preamble.

```
\glssetwidest[1]{mmmmmm} % modify to move description to the left
\renewcommand*{\glstreenamebox}[2]{%
    \ifnum\glscurrententrylevel=1 % is supposed to check if entry is a child
    \makebox[#1][l]{\hspace{-10em}#2} % move name to left if is child
    \else
    \makebox[#1][l]{#2} %default value
    \fi
}
```

However, it seems that `\glscurrententrylevel=1` is always true. Despite having a parent node (shouldn't it be level 0?) with a child.

**MWE** (without effort from above):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{tocloft} % for dots in glossary

\usepackage[record, stylemods={default}, style={alttree}, toc=false]{glossaries-extra} %glossary package (with bib2gls)
\GlsXtrLoadResources[src={exampleentries}, break-at={none},type={main}] % loading glossary file exampleentries.bib

% Formatting glossary
\glssetcategoryattribute{general}{glossnamefont}{textbf} % entry name in boldface
\glssetcategoryattribute{general}{glossdescfont}{textit} % entry description in italic
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}} % dots in glossary
\renewcommand*\glspostdescription{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}} % dots in glossary

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry} % for margin changing
\newgeometry{margin=2.5cm} % reasonable 2.5 cm margin

\overfullrule=10mm % black box if margin exceeded

\begin{document}

Example text with \gls*{longest-entry-in-glossary} and \gls*{child-of-longest-entry}. And \gls*{some-other-entry}. % example text

\renewcommand{\glossarypreamble}{\glsfindwidesttoplevelname[\currentglossary]} %spacing between name and description
{\footnotesize \printunsrtglossary[type=main]} %print glossary

\end{document}
```

The file `exampleentries.bib`:

```
@entry{longest-entry-in-glossary,
name={This is the longest entry name in here},
text={The longest},
description={Description goes here}
}

@entry{child-of-longest-entry,
parent={longest-entry-in-glossary},
name={Name of child is here},
text={child node},
description={Description goes here too, but may be too long otherwise}
}

@entry{some-other-entry,
name={Name of another entry},
text={another entry},
description={Description foo}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding to the preamble:

```
\glssetwidest[1]{mm} % modify to move description to the left (essentially "mm" longest name of child entries, where "mm" is ficticious)
\renewcommand*{\glstreenamebox}[2]{% modifying \glstreenamebox accordingly
    \glsxtrifhasfield{parent}% if-clause
    {\glscurrententrylabel}% checking to see if a correspoding entry with \glscurrententrylabel in exampleentries.bib has "parent=", i.e. if it's a child
    {\makebox[#1][l]{\makebox[#1][l]{\hspace{-10em}#2}}}% if it is a child, move to the left by 10 em (change as necessary)
    {\makebox[#1][l]{#2}}} % if it is not a child, default value of \glstreenamebox
```

Here, the `\glssetwidest` is used to manipulate the distance between of level-1 (child) name and description. You may modify `mm` accordingly to other length strings.

The `\renewcommand*{\glstreenamebox}` is for changing the distance of a name from the left margin. The `\glstreenamebox` is used regardless of whether the entry is a child or not, so we need an if-clause inside the redefinition. This is what the `\glscurrententrylabel{<field>}{<entry label>}{<do-if-true>}{<do-if-false>}` achieves. We need to accertain if an entry is a child or not before we do anything.

- If the current entry in glossary (provided by `\glscurrententrylabel`) has a parent, then it will have `parent=` in the `exampleentries.bib` file. So, for normal glossaries, if the field `parent` is present, it is a child; otherwise it is not.

If it is a child, we prepend `\hspace{-10em}`, shifting the name of the child to the left by `10 em`. Otherwise, we keep the default value of `\glstreenamebox` which here is `\makebox[#1][l]{#2}}`. Modify `10 em` as required.

[image: Output of MWE with changes made to preamble]